# Loop through file names Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I am new to Java, so bear with me.

I have just added a link to a much larger project, got it working to open a pdf file.

Here is the section in the jsp for the link -

```
<li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
  <a class="sub dropdown-item pr-1" tabindex="-1" href="#">Help Menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="helpMenu">
    <li id="setupItemOne"><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href='<s:url action="downloadPdfAction"><s:param name="reqGuid" value="%{reqGuid}"/></s:url>'><span class='fa fa-info-circle pr-1'></span> How To Set Up Item One</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I created DownloadPdfAction.java and here is the section of code from that which calls the .pdf file -

```
public class DownloadPdfAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, LoginRequired  {

static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DownloadPdfAction.class);
private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
private String reqGuid;

private InputStream fileInputStream;

public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
    return fileInputStream;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/web_apps/server/external/Item_One_Installation.pdf"));
        return SUCCESS;
     } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

Works fine.  Now I need to add several other links pointing to other .pdf files in the same spot.  Rather than creating a new action.java page for each link, is there a way for me to pick the .pdf file name for the "new File" based on which link was clicked and put that file into a variable name for FileInputStream in DownloadPdfAction.java?  The .pdfs are all in the same directory.

Comment: Create a string attribute filename inside of DownloadPDFAction, create a form inside your jsp that is submitted on click of the downloadPdfUrl that has an input labeled the same as your DownloadPDFAction filename attribute. That is how I would go about this (in a pseudocode type of manner utilizing struts jquery)

Comment: @plum 0 Using what you said, I think I've come up with a way so that I can put the name of the file as an `s:param` within the link and then feed it through a variable in the Action.  Will finish and test it tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how it goes!